# Book about a world of elfin-like creatures with bumps on their foreheads

Tags: story-identification, books, art

It was a children's book my aunt once got me.  Its a book about a world of elfin like creatures with bumps on their foreheads who are very akin to druids and kindly villagers and grotesque goblin like folk who live among them as guards and bureaucrats.  The book came with a ribbon book mark with a card to translate the runes throughout the book.  I cant recall the name but I do remember the name of the dark overlord entity the book alluded to.  Mulcifer, I believe it was.  The last few pages of the book were a map of the land with many of these runed massages and a large hedge maze followed by a mural of the more elfin folk dresses in robes with a golden apple. If anybody can help me with the name I'd be greatly appreciative.

Small update.  Three recurring characters who appear throughout the book.  All three are of the elf like race and I believe are all in the front cover.  The first is a chubby chronicler who is supposed to be writing what your reading.  He is dressed in robes similar to a midevil friar.  The other two are small children.  A boy and a girl.  I dont remember clearly what they wore but I think the boy wore overhauls and a red cap and the girl a plain dress. Similar to maybe German or Scandinavian  clothing.  The chronicler appears occasionally but the children are often experiencing what is being written about.  Either playing or sneaking about.

The book is formatted similarly to the Ology books (Dragonology, Wizardology, etc.) as opposed to a straight forward story.

Comment: Do you remember roughly when you read the book?

Comment: Roughly between 1998-2003.  I dont remember when I got it exactly but I do remember when I had it last

Answer (score 4):

For those who may be curious, I found the book.

*[Caleb Beldragon's Chronicle of the Three Counties](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4599022-caleb-beldragons-chronicle-of-the-three-counties)* by Paul Warren.

[image: Book cover]

> Long oppressed by the ruthless Lord Mulciber, the Gibblins hope to restore their exiled king by finding a legendary stone called the Malbigon.

Comment: You should be able to accept your answer in another day or two by clicking on the checkmark,. Please do.